# Tumblr display photoset posts as a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I'm working on a new blog theme that I started about an hour ago, and sadly I've already hit a bump in the road. The theme is wide-set, meaning it is wider than tumblr's default photo, photoset, and video size. I've already conquered the photo size (wasn't that hard!) and the video size (thank god, I've been trying to resize videos for months!) but I'm stuck at photosets. I found the plugin "photoset killer" very helpful, but it doesn't completely do the job. I'd like to use a script that kills the layout of the photoset (display just the images one after another), resizes all of the images to exactly 728 pixels, even if they're stretched, and then display them in a slide show. I know this sounds complicated, but it's really not once you think about it. I don't need a fancy slide show at all, just a 728 x the height of the tallest photo in the photoset, that has arrows on the sides to navigate between photos. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, and the website i'm doing it on is http://jamestestblog.tumblr.com/

Edit: I've seen this done before and it IS possible, I just don't remember where. It may have been on a pixel union theme. I really need help here guys..

Answer (score 1):

In [tumblr documentation for photosets](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts) `{block:Photos} {/block:Photos}` block exists, which will be executed so many times, as how many images are in the photoset. Try to output each image in photoset with this block.
Images will be not in an iframe and full under your `CSS` control, with this trick.